# seaborn cycle through colours with matplotlib scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I get seaborn colors when doing a scatter plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
for f in files:
    ax.scatter(args) # all datasets end up same colour
    #plt.plot(args) #  cycles through palette correctly
```

Comment: This is a 'feature', not a 'bug'  `scatter` is a `ScalarMappable` which means you can assign a scalar value to each marker which will than be used (along with a color map) to color each marker according to the scalar value.  Given that, having `scatter` participate in the color cycle logic seems silly/too fiddly.  As a side note, unless you are varying the size of the markers, it is probably better to use `plot` with no line (it will go faster).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using plot :) I was not suggesting it was a bug, was just asking how to do it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have to tell matplotlib which color to use. To Use, for example, seaborn's default color palette:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import itertools
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

palette = itertools.cycle(sns.color_palette())

for f in files:
    ax.scatter(args, color=next(palette))
```

The [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) makes sure we don't run out of colors and start with the first one again after using the last one.

**Update:**

As per @Iceflower's comment, creating a custom color palette via

```
palette = sns.color_palette(None, len(files))
```

might be a better solution. The difference is that my original answer at the top iterates through the default colors as often as it has to, whereas this solution creates a palette with as much hues as there are files. That means that no color is repeated, but the difference between colors might be very subtle.

Comment: Better use `sns.color_palette(None, len(files)` https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html

Answer (score 2):

To build on Carsten's answer, if you have a large number of categories to assign colours to, you might wish to zip the colours to a very large seaborn palette, for example the [`xkcd_palette`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.xkcd_palette.html#seaborn.xkcd_palette) or [`crayon_palette`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.crayon_palette.html#seaborn.crayon_palette).. Note that this practice is usually [a chartjunk anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk): using more than 5-6 colours is usually overkill, and you might need to consider changing your chart type.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

palette = zip(df['category'].unique(), sns.crayons.values())
```