# Python: Seaborn Getting Hex values of a color palette (or color palette is not working with scatter)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Well I am plotting pandas dataframes df1, df2 and df3. I have a list of df's.

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]


sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette("dark"))

def plot_data(col1,col2,PLOT_TYPE):
    for df in list_df:
         if PLOT_TYPE == "time"
             plt.plot(df[col1], df[col2]) #this works as expected, each df has different colors
         else
             plt.scatter(df[col1], df[col2]) #this plots every df as  same color (blue), and the color is not from dark palette 

plot_data("time", "values", "time")
plot_data("size", "values", "scatter)
```

I can solve by explicitly indicating a color for each dataframe with `c=dark_palette[i]` , to do that 
I need the colors of the dark palette, how can I do that?  (other than plotting palette, and using an eyedropper in GIMP)? Also, why the palette does not work with scatter?

**EDIT:** also when I change **plt.plot** in **if block** to **plt.scatter**, again I get all the same colors (i.e. blue)

I think this is an issue with matplotlib, here minimum code

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
y1= x**2
y2 = x**3
plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.show()

plt.scatter(x, y1)
plt.scatter(x, y2)
plt.show()
```

Solution : [seaborn cycle through colours with matplotlib scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430385/seaborn-cycle-through-colours-with-matplotlib-scatter/28430505#28430505)

Comment: It's a bit hard understanding what's going on in your code, what is `PLOT_TYPE` and how does it change? You should try to put together a reproducible example that people can get running just by copy-pasting into their console.

Comment: @Marius added a reproducible example. Looks like a matplotlib issue, not seaborn.

Comment: I found a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28430505/1222578), looks like it's part of matplotlib's design to not have the color cycling apply to scatter plots. The answer to that question should allow you to cycle colours for your scatter plots.

Comment: thank you Marius, good job.